# How to reset samba password in nautilus in Ubintu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, samba

I used to connect with local file server with nautilus. Everything worked fine until i saved password. After that when i try to connect i get message: `Unable to access connection: Failed to retrieve file list from server: Connection refused`. When i manually connect by writing server address in nautilus connect to server field - it works. How can i clear stored password? In passwords and keys application i see only gery mail passwords. /etc/samaba/ folder is not used in this ubuntu version (20.04).

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu area you using? Please add the new information in the question using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1233063/edit) function.